# How to create widget category of elementor on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web, elementor

I want to add a new category to element editor on wordpress.
I found the link https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/,
but I don' t know what to do. Because I am a beginner.
How to add that codes, to what file.
I mean step by step.
How to make a php file in any path, and how to include that php file?
I can create a new php file for it? or insert them to current elementor php file?

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate file ( e.g: helper.php) in your plugin folder and include it into your main plugin loader file. paste the following code into the helper file. And that will create a separate category in the Elementor's widget sidebar.

```
<?php 
namespace Elementor;

function category_elementor_init(){
    Plugin::instance()->elements_manager->add_category(
        'category-for-elementor',
        [
            'title'  => 'Elementor Category',
            'icon' => 'font'
        ],
        1
    );
}
add_action('elementor/init', 'Elementor\category_elementor_init');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Robi. But I want to know in detail- step by step.

Comment: What do you mean with `namespace Elementor` ?

Answer (score 2):

As like the documentation: [Getting Started for extending Elementor](https://developers.elementor.com/getting-started/)

Create a custom plugin first, hope you know How to create a custom plugin: [Create plugins in wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)

**A short demo:**
Remember full **Elementor core** is written in **OOP**.
Assuming the plugin name as **ElementorTest**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: ElementorTest
 * Plugin URI:  https://example.com/plugins/ElementorTest/
 * Description: Basic Elementor Extension
 * Version:     1.1
 * Author:      Ahmed Maruf
 * Author URI:  https://author.example.com/
 * License:     GPL2
 * License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain: elementortestplugin
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */
```

Now, we need to make sure that **no direct** access is given to our plugin php files,     and let us **create** the **basic skeleton** for creating an **extension/widget** via **Elementor**.Ref: [Initialize the plugin](https://developers.elementor.com/creating-an-extension-for-elementor/)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}



final class Elementor_Test_Extension {

        const VERSION = "1.1"; //Your plugin version
        const MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION = "2.0.0"; //Minimum Elementor Version Required
        const MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION = "7.0"; //Minimum PHP version required to run your plugin

        private static $_instance = null;
        /*The plugin class should use a singleton design pattern to make sure it loads only once*/
        public static function instance() {
            if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
             self::$_instance = new self();
         }return self::$_instance;

     }
     /*

      The constructor should initiate the plugin. The init process should check for basic requirements and then then run the plugin logic. Note that If one of the basic plugin requirements fails the plugin logic won’t run.
      */
      public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ $this, 'init' ] );
    }
    /*Initialize all the basic requirements to run the plugin logic*/
    public function init() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'elementortestplugin' );

        // Check if Elementor installed and activated
        if ( ! did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_missing_main_plugin' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Check for required Elementor version
        if ( ! version_compare( ELEMENTOR_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION, '>=' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_minimum_elementor_version' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Check for required PHP version
        if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION, '<' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_minimum_php_version' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Add Plugin actions when rest requirements are passed
        add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this, 'init_widgets' ] );     

    }
    /*Callback function for the action hook admin notices*/
    public function admin_notice_missing_main_plugin() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: Elementor */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" to be installed and activated.', 'elementortestplugin' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>'
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }

    /*Callback function for action hook admin notices upon elementor version not matching*/
    public function admin_notice_minimum_elementor_version() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: Elementor 3: Required Elementor version */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" version %3$s or greater.', 'elementortestplugin' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>',
            self::MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }
    /*Callback function for action hood admin notices upon php version not matched*/
    public function admin_notice_minimum_php_version() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: PHP 3: Required PHP version */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" version %3$s or greater.', 'elementortestplugin' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'PHP', 'elementortestplugin' ) . '</strong>',
            self::MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }

    /*
    @Callback function for the action hook elementor/widgets/widgets_registered
    @Create the folder widgets and the file under you custom plugin /widgets/test-widget.php
    */
    public function init_widgets() {

        // Include Widget files
        require_once( __DIR__ . '/widgets/test-widget.php' );

        // Register widget by creating the class in the file you have created naming as test-widget.php
        \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor_Test_Widget() );

    }

    public function includes() {}

}
Elementor_Test_Extension::instance();
```

Now create a class under youtplugin/widgets/test-widget.php. Ref: [Creating the core widget functionality](https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/)

```
class Elementor_Test_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base
{
    /**
     * Define your core logic for the widget
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

Rest are pretty self explanatory. For widget category the skeleton is also similar. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I have a issue to fix. I have added the following code

Comment: @Michael, great to know you have solved the issue. Apart from this here is the details of the code which output a custom category along with widgets in it. You can have a watch over this: [link](https://github.com/Ahmed-Maruf/custom/tree/master/Elementor%20Test)